# How to make 3 column row from API data in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

First time doing this so please bear with me.

Using Bootstrap. Trying to make some data present itself as a 3 column row. And at the end of each row, make a new row.

Is there a way to do this with the code below?

Code sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/hjdr6?file=/src/components/MachineList.js).

Here's the code:

```
      <input
        className="search"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search by model..."
        onChange={(e) => setSearchValue(e.target.value)}
        value={searchValue}
      />
      {/* Map through first level */}
      {data.map((item) => (
        <ul>
          {/* Filter and map through the second level */}
          {item.product_details.filter(filterProducts).map((subItem) => (
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-lg-4">
                <MachineCard
                  image={subItem.image}
                  title={subItem.model}
                  weight={subItem.operating_weight}
                  power={subItem.power}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </ul>
      ))}
```

Comment: That's basically how it would be done. What specifically are you having trouble with? Incidentally, when you're creating an array of things for react to render, react appreciates having a key prop. so `<div className="row">` should be `<div className="row" key="some identifier from subitem">`

Comment: You need either make your MachineCard component to have the col classes, but your problem is that currently you're just using one column of size 4, you need 3 of them  to split the data as you want.

Comment: @CharlesBamford I've updated my post with a link to the codesandbox. 

It currently renders all items in one straight column. I've also adjusted the code and wrapped the 'col-lg-4' in the MachineCard component.

Any idea why it's not rendering a 3 column row?

Comment: @jean182 thanks, any idea how to accomplish that?